# how to use redis-lock to use locking

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, node-redis

I am trying to use redis-lock (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-lock) but it is throwing the error please let me know what is going wrong here

```
test();

async function test()
{
    
    const client = require('redis').createClient();
    
    const { promisify } = require('util');
    
    const lock = promisify(require('redis-lock')(client));
    
    client.on('connect', function(){
        console.log('Connected to Redis');
    });
    
    client.on('error', function(err) {
         console.log('Redis error: ' + err);
    });
    const unlock = await lock('lockString');
    // Perform your task;
    
    unlock();
    
}
```

Error

(node:22972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: You must specify a client instance of http://github.com/mranney/node_redis
at module.exports (E:\XPA-GS(replacement)\Test\node_modules\redis-lock\index.js:23:9)
at Test\test-redis-lock.js:46:59
at step (Test\test-redis-lock.js:32:23)
at Object.next (Test\test-redis-lock.js:13:53)
at Test\test-redis-lock.js:7:71
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (Test\test-redis-lock.js:3:12)
at test (Test\test-redis-lock.js:39:12)
at Object. (Test\test-redis-lock.js:37:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `await client.connect()` after creating the client if you are using [node-redis](https://github.com/redis/node-redis)